# NSClickGestureRecognizer not working as supposed (requires one click more)

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks

I'm using NSClickGestureRecognizer for my os x app. But it does not work as supposed. When I set required number of clicks to 1 it fires after 2 clicks. When I set it to 2 it fires after 3...

I use it like this:

```
NSClickGestureRecognizer *click = [[NSClickGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
click.target = self;
click.delegate = self;
click.numberOfClicksRequired = 1;
click.action = @selector(fireworksClicked:);

[self.fireworksView addGestureRecognizer:click];
```

The code above only fires after double click. Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to overwrite

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
```

in your fireworksView to return YES.

Comment: God bless you @Marc T